# jQuery AJAX call not triggering correct callback

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I've got an AJAX call that is supposed to trigger a designated callback for each HTTP return code I'm expecting. However, for some reason, when I send HTTP code 100 (named "Continue"), jQuery executes the callback for HTTP code 200 (named "OK"). Why does it execute the wrong callback?

```
var event_properties =
{
    // ... filled in properties.
};
var ajax_post =
{
    "data": event_properties,
    "type": "POST",
    "dataType": "json",
    "statusCode": { 100: get_reservation_configuration, 200: reservation_creation_success_callback }
};
jQuery.ajax("/create_reservation/", ajax_post).fail(reservation_creation_failure_callback);
```

And, on a side note, am I using anything that is deprecated in jQuery? I'm trying not to, but the documentation is a little unclear.